# How to build a package for Tkinter like exe in window?

Tags: python, linux, user-interface, tkinter

In windows, we can use pyinstaller to build python code like Tkinter to an exe file for user use, How to in Linux, I don't like user to do it in terminal to run the code, Any advice? Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux comes with Python preinstalled, so on Linux you can just prepend a shebang `#!` line with the path to the interpreter to a Python script and then set the executable bit `+x` on the file with `chmod`. Then you can run it by name or click on it in the file explorer application.

If you need more than one file, you can use the zipapp module to group a folder together into a single executable .pyz archive with the shebang.